# Outside column categorizing the paragraph

Tags: macros, two-column, multicolumn, documentclass-writing, paracol

I'm looking to write a report where the **outside column** helps to categorize de paragraph on its side, as you can see in the attached image. The blue text acts like a "title" to some of the most important paragraphs. How can I achieve this in Latex? This will be used multiple times along the report.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document-snippet on the image looks like a snippet of a one-column-document to me, where the command `\marginpar` is used for placing notes into the margin, with text-color blue and text in `\raggedleft` for left-hand-pages (where page-numbers are even) and probably text in `\raggedright` for right-hand-pages (where page-numbers are odd). (Be aware that with `\raggedleft`/`\raggedright` you need to make sure that `\par` is carried out while these "switches" are in effect.)

Could be something like this—the command `\ifthispageodd` from the package `scrextend` is used for detecting the parity of the page-number of the page where the margin-paragraph is placed; in order to cope with the 
asynchrony of (La)TeX's output-routines due to which evaluating the current value of the page counter is not reliable, `\ifthispageodd` in turn internally places and evaluates referencing-labels which means that you need to compile the document at least twice until everything matches out:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{color}

{\normalfont\normalsize
\expandafter}\expandafter\parskip\expandafter=\the\ht\strutbox

\parindent=0em

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  This is blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  Blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.

\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  This is blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  Blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.

\newpage

\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  This is blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  Blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.

\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  This is blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  Blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.

\newpage

\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  This is blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  Blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.

\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  This is blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.
\leavevmode\marginpar{%
  \begingroup
  \leavevmode
  \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%
  \itshape
  \color{blue}%
  Blue text.%
  \par
  \endgroup
}%
This is main text. This is main text. This is main text. This is main text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]